# Websocket “Base Asset Volume” is not matching with binance candle stick charts

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

There is an extreme mismatch between “Base Asset Volume” that I am getting from binance WebSocket to live candlesticks chart on there website.

On the socket output, the volume is 18502 and on the candlestick chart it's 58.39K. Please check the attached chart for reference.

Using 1-minute interval

Using UTC timezone on charts

```
11/28/2021, 05:20:00 {‘stream’: ‘keepusdt@kline_1m’, ‘data’: {‘e’: ‘kline’, ‘E’: 1638076860341, ‘s’: ‘KEEPUSDT’, ‘k’: {‘t’: 1638076800000, ‘T’: 1638076859999, ‘s’: ‘KEEPUSDT’, ‘i’: ‘1m’, ‘f’: 11464779, ‘L’: 11464818, ‘o’: ‘0.80220000’, ‘c’: ‘0.80230000’, ‘h’: ‘0.80230000’, ‘l’: ‘0.80030000’, ‘v’: ‘18502.00000000’, ‘n’: 40, ‘x’: True, ‘q’: ‘14831.19770000’, ‘V’: ‘15179.00000000’, ‘Q’: ‘12167.98410000’, ‘B’: ‘0’}}}
```

[Compare with the candlestick chart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK0MF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved in another forum

was listening to spot stream instead of Future stream

changed from :

wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=

to

wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=

Working as expected now.